# Short-sighted and Near-sighted

Tags: phrases

I've always thought that Short-sighted means that you fail to look far into the future when planning. I thought near-sighted meant that your focusing ability in your eyes becomes less powerful as you move further from the object you are looking at.

I noticed thesaurus.com has them as essentially meaning the [same](http://thesaurus.com/browse/near-sighted) [thing](http://thesaurus.com/browse/short-sighted); multiple things.

What is the correct definitions of these phrases?

Comment: My personal definition/usage of these terms agrees with yours. I would never use "short-sighted" to describe someone who needs glasses for distance vision, and I wouldn't use "nearsighted" to describe someone who failed to plan ahead. I would, however, use the word "myopic" in both contexts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The NOAD reports that *short-sighted* is

- the British term for nearsighted
- the word meaning *lacking imagination or foresight*

*Nearsighted* is reported to mean *unable to see things clearly unless they are relatively close to the eyes, owing to the focusing of rays of light by the eye at a point in front of the retina*.

In American English, the words have two different meaning.

Comment: So if a British person confides to an American that they are short sighted, the American thinks they are admitting to a lack of ability to plan ahead? I never knew...

Comment: Perhaps more to the point, if you call an American short-sighted, it will be taken as an insult.

Answer (score 4):

Considering that Myopia and the adjective myopic can be [used to refer to both the Ophtamalogical condition as well as the mental condition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/myopic) I think that you can feel comfortable using these terms interchangeably.

Comment: Interesting take on it

Comment: I agree. I always call myself short-sighted wrt my optical problems.

Answer (score 4):

According to my copy of the OED:
**short-sighted** *adj.* **1** having short sight. **2** lacking imagination or foresight.
**near-sighted** *adj.* esp. *US* = short-sighted.

Comment: agree, near-sighted sounds very american to me.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at dictionary.com's definitions ([nearsighted](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nearsighted), [shortsighted](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/shortsighted) ), they do pretty much mean the same thing. I think "shortsighted" is used slightly more often to mean "failing to plan," but they can both be used that way.

Answer (score 1):

I (Irish) wouldn't use *near-sighted* at all. I'd use *short-sighted* in both contexts (and I'm short-sighted myself).